# Best way to trigger an action when a many to many field is added or removed in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to figure out the best way to achieve the following, but having no luck. I guess ideally I would like to over ride the add method for the specific field. Is this possible?

Given the following model

```
class SomeGroup(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

I would like to trigger the below methods anytime SomeGroup.users.add(user) or SomeGroup.users.remove(user) is called

```
def on_user_add()
    print("{} has been added".format(user))

def on_user_remove()
    print("{} has been removed".format(user))
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [**`m2m_changed`** signal [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#m2m-changed):

```
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed

def on_user_add_rem(sender, instance, action, pk_set, **kwargs)
    if action == 'post_add':
        print(f'{pk_set} has been added')
    elif action == 'post_remove':
        print(f'{pk_set} has been removed')

m2m_changed.connect(on_user_add_rem, sender=SomeGroup.users.through)
```

Here `pk_set` is the set of added/removed primary keys. You can however make a query to fetch the corresponding `User` object.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed.